# What is the difference between these two queries of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

These 2 queries fetching the same column at the same conditions. But still result is different:

**First Using Joins:**

```
select 
  s.codice as codice,
  n.ragione_sociale as ragione_sociale  
from 
  parco_veicoli pv
right join 
  noleggiatori n on pv.id_noleggiatore = n.id
right join 
  sedi s on pv.id_sede = s.id  
  order by codice, ragione_sociale;
```

First query giving total 1323 rows in output.

**Second Without Joins:**

```
SELECT 
  s.codice as codice,
  n.ragione_sociale as ragione_sociale
FROM 
  parco_veicoli pv,  
  noleggiatori n, 
  sedi s
WHERE 
  pv.id_sede = s.id AND
  pv.id_noleggiatore = n.id 
  order by codice, ragione_sociale;
```

Second query giving total 1321 rows in output.

**Question:**

Can anyone tell me that the meaning of both queries is same or different?

Because output is almost same but only result set (rows) are less of 2nd query than 1st query.

Comment: have you tried to execute the two queries?

Comment: Yes i tried in pg admin console. Output is almost same what rows in output of second query is less than first query.

Comment: The first query returns all rows in `sedi` even if it has no matches in table `parco_veicoli`. However, the second query is an old syntax of `INNER JOIN` in which it only display rows if there are matching rows that meet within the condition.

Comment: Yes 1st query returning all codice from sedi. But in 2nd query all codice is not there. Can you explain which one will be better?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM section join_type

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html

> FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2 is equivalent to FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON TRUE
>   (see below). It is also equivalent to FROM T1, T2.

and

> RIGHT OUTER JOIN
>
> First, an inner join is performed. Then, for each row in T2 that does
>   not satisfy the join condition with any row in T1, a joined row is
>   added with null values in columns of T1. This is the converse of a
>   left join: the result table will always have a row for each row in T2.

so in your queries second is `INNER` join and the first is `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`